# Can you tell me what is the time complexity (Big-O) of my function?

Tags: c++, arrays, big-o

Function receives an array, length of array
and number of consecutive elements of an array.
I run an array and look for the maximum sum of 'K' consecutive elements

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int GetLargestSum(int array[], int length, int k)
{
    int largestSum = 0;
    int previousSum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= length - k; i++){
        if (i == 0){
            for (int j = 0; j < k; j++){
                largestSum += array[j];
            }
            previousSum = largestSum;
        } else{
            int currentSum = previousSum - array[i - 1] + array[i + k - 1];
            if (currentSum > largestSum){
                largestSum = currentSum;
            }
            previousSum = currentSum;
        }
    }
    return largestSum;
}

int main(){
    int k = 3;
    int array[] = {1, -3, 4, 1, 7, -5, 9};
    cout << "Largest sum of " << k << " consecutive elements of an array = " << GetLargestSum(array, 7, 3);
}
```

Comment: I see nested for loops, I default to O(n^2). Nothing stops the `k` elements from being at the end of the array.

Comment: Nothing stops the `k` elements from being at the end of the array but the inner loop executes `k` many times, and only once not once per outer loop execution. Looks `O(n)` to me.

Comment: The `k` doesn't change, so it looks like `O(N*K)`

Comment: Yeah, you guys looked at it harder than me. Being facetious, if `k` approaches `n` ...

Comment: It would probably be advantageous for readability (and analysis ;)) to take the code for the first iteration off the for-loop entirely, place it _before_ the for-lop and let the loop start at `i = 1`.

Comment: I agree with Reizo: If you know only a single iteration executes some logic in the loop body usually it's preferrable to rewrite the code and remove the `if` from the loop. Usually the compiler optimizes this on it's own, but for certain optimization settings you may get less performant code. In this case it's important to check `k <= length`  before running the inner loop of course...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of analysing complexity is to find out largely how much time (time complexity), storage (storage complexity) or memory (memory complexity) an algorithm is using. For this we tend to think about (infinitely) large dimensions, because if the dimensions are very small, we tend not to care them about too much. Your algorithm depends on the number of elements and on the number of consecutive elements.

Assuming that there are (infinitely) many elements, nothing stops k from being large either. In the first step of iterating all elements, but only in the first step (!) you do an O(k)-complex loop. After that you continue to proceed looping your elements and you perform an O(1) operation on each step, n times, which is n * O(1) = O(n).

Now, you have O(k) + O(n), which, since there is no parallelization between the two and no other tricks, results in O(k + n). Since k < n, O(k + n) < O(2n) and O(2n) = O(n), basically you have a linear algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer but a hint:

As noted in my comment, you can prepend the inner for loop to the outer. The result is shown below. I've also removed the redundant variable `previousSum` and compute the initial sum in `currentSum`. My function should behave identical to yours, provided that `k <= length`.

```
int GetLargestSum(int array[], int length, int k)
{
    int currentSum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
        currentSum += array[j];
    }

    int largestSum = currentSum;
    for (int i = 0; i < length - k; i++) {
        int currentSum += array[i + k] - array[i];
        if (currentSum > largestSum) {
            largestSum = currentSum;
        }
    }
    return largestSum;
}
```

`i` still starts at `0`, because I removed the `- 1`'s in the index accesses and do a strict less comparison in the for-condition (`<` instead of `<=`). `i` is now always the index of the summand that's "removed" from `currentSum` next.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, the code does the following :

- first, traverses the first K elements and get the sum
- From now, it will just add the next incoming element and remove the first element of the current window and check if this sum is greater or lesser compared to the current sum.

So this way you traverse the array only once. So O(N) (N is length of array)

Answer (score 0):

The `if (i == 0) ... else ...` is an obfuscated way of writing the same thing outside of the loop and starting the loop at `1`:

```
int GetLargestSum(int array[], int length, int k)
{
    int largestSum = 0;
    int previousSum = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < k; j++){
        largestSum += array[j];
    }
    previousSum = largestSum;

    for (int i = 1; i <= length - k; i++){
        int currentSum = previousSum - array[i - 1] + array[i + k - 1];
        if (currentSum > largestSum){
            largestSum = currentSum;
        }
        previousSum = currentSum;
    }
    return largestSum;
}
```

Now we can remove all parts that take constant number of operations:

```
int GetLargestSum(int array[], int length, int k)
{
    // init something 

    for (int j = 0; j < k; j++){
        // do something
    }

    // do something

    for (int i = 1; i <= length - k; i++){
        // do something
    }
    return largestSum;
}
```

And we can see that the complexity is `O ( max( k, length-k) )` and as `k <= length` this is just `O( length )`